How might I make this expect script consistently work as expected?
I use an interactive wallet spectre-cli of Spectre, a coin similar to
Kaspa in its design.
When I manually want to get the balance of my wallet I need to run
spectre-cli and then connect, open
from within spectre-cli. All this looks like this:
spectre-cli
Spectre Cli Wallet v0.3.16 (type 'help' for list of commands)
$ connect
Connected to Spectre node version 0.3.16 at ws://127.0.0.1:19110
$ open
Enter wallet password: 

Your wallet hint is: This is a hint.

$ $ 
• ****************
    • [********]: 4.47042578 SPR   1 UTXOs
      spectre:******************************************************

[********] • 4.47042578 SPR $ 


I wrote an expect script meant to do those steps for me (so that the only thing I
would need to type is my password):
#!/usr/bin/expect -f

# Set a timeout (in seconds) for how long to wait for each prompt
set timeout 5

spawn spectre-cli

expect "$ "   
send "connect\r"

expect "$ "  
send "open\r"


interact


I get inconsistent output from the script. About 70% of the time I get:
./get_balance_works.exp 
spawn spectre-cli
Spectre Cli Wallet v0.3.16 (type 'help' for list of commands)
$ connect
connectopen
command not found: connectopen
$ 

whereas the rest of the time the script works as expected:
./get_balance_works.exp 
spawn spectre-cli
Spectre Cli Wallet v0.3.16 (type 'help' for list of commands)
$ connect
$ open
Connected to Spectre node version 0.3.16 at ws://127.0.0.1:19110
Enter wallet password: 

Your wallet hint is: This is a hint.

$ $ 
• ****************
    • [********]: 4.47042578 SPR   1 UTXOs
      spectre:******************************************************

[********] • 4.47042578 SPR $ 

Is there a way to make the script work as expected in a consistent manner?
P.S. I am on a Ubuntu LTS.

Add option -d for debug. It is usually a good idea to handle timeouts explicitly since they can
cause chaos. Since you are interactively running your script, give it a
large timeout, like 120 seconds, so it will be obvious when a pattern is
not recognised. Or match timeout in this way: expect timeout exit "$ ",
which at least stops the script from continuing.

Maybe it's due to an unstable buffer interface, similar to apt (not apt-get) when it tries to capture the output from its buffer. Maybe using readings like "command inversion" with "read", "IFS" and some printf you can achieve it. If you want I can try to explain better or digress more about this possibility.

@meuh I replaced expect "$ " with expect timeout exit "$ " in my script and it still succeds only 30% of the time. When it does not succeed it just exits, without trying to send connectopen

@meuh Increasing the timeout to 120 made the script work as expected about 70% of the time.

It possibly depends on how fast the commands arrive, and thus you may need to introduce "human like" delays?
from Expect man page:
The -h flag forces output to be sent (somewhat) like a human actually typing.
 Human-like delays appear between the characters. 
# or a bit further down:
the following command emulates a fast and consistent typist:
set send_human {.1 .3 1 .05 2}


Spot on. Thank you. No need for set timeout 120, just set send_slow {1 .2} below the shebang and than replacing send with send -s solved the matter.

It looks like this utility in rust is using
workflow-terminal,
which is calling crossterm
or termion to do its work, and this is more of a
curses-like
command line interface, rather than simple text i/o. This can be
challenging to work with. For your usage, the simple answer may be to match
only for "$" rather than "$ " as, for example, the interface might just
be moving the cursor right to simulate the space, and no space can be matched.
It might explain how the \r at the end of send "connect\r" gets lost
somehow.
Since expect treats $ at the end of a glob as an anchor, the string
"$" always matches an empty string, i.e. immediately, whatever is read.
To stop it treating the string as a glob you need to add option -exact,
so use in both places:
expect -exact "$"


Thanks for your answer. Sadly, matching only for "$" has not solved the matter - I get identical output.

Oops, expect treats $ at the end of a glob as an anchor, so "$" always matches an empty string, i.e. everything! To stop it treating the string as a glob you need to add option -exact, so use expect -exact "$" in both places.
